# Validate Form Fields having [ or ] in names OR with ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using `jquery.validate.min.js` for Form field validations.

I have some fields with names like `JFromField[contactname]` (its becasue I am using Joomla, and its coming from backend) means they have `[` and `]` in the names.

So in the Rules, how do I do that?

```
   rules:{
           myFieldName : {    required: true     }
         }
```

And another question is can specify the `rules` based on `ID`?

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#fields-with-complex-names-(brackets-dots)

Answer (score 0):

Since `[` or `]` is not a valid identifier, you can pass the key as a string like

```js
$('form').validate({
  rules: {
    myFieldName: {
      required: true
    },
    'JFromField[contactname]': {
      required: true
    }
  }
});

//to simulate validation since form submit is prevented
$('#save').click(function(){
  return $('form').valid()
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

<form>
  <input name="myFieldName" />
  <br />
  <input name="JFromField[contactname]" />
  <br />
  <input type="button" id="save" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: This does not seem to work at my end:(

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of javascript objects. Use " or ' to assign fields with [ ] to objects. And use ["field"] to get values.

```
var r = { rules: { "JFromField[contactname]" : {    required: true     } } };
console.log(r);
console.log(r.rules);
console.log(r.rules["JFromField[contactname]"]);
console.log(r.rules["JFromField[contactname]"].required);
```

Comment: Please explain what you are doing *by editing your answer*.